# Even i change permissions i m getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: javascript, php, permissions, chmod

i change on filezilla all permission of my folder and files to 755,

But i'm getting Error like this  Failed to load resource http://exams-english.com/ressources/toeic/test1_part3_1.mp3 Fai : the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
 i'm trying to read a mp3 file, on local everithing work fine

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did not specify .mp3 and now it works because this url is valid

http://exams-english.com/ressources/toeic/test1_part3_1

and

this one is not http://exams-english.com/ressources/toeic/test1_part3_1.mp3